# HTML fetch Table/DIV from extern website

Tags: html

As my title states it, I am building a HTML app and for that I need to get some data from a website which I do not have database acces too. So this seemed like a good way to get around that. Also I am not going to use iframes in this.

Comment: You can use JS, can't you?

Comment: Can you please give us some more information? You can't use iframes, that is ok. But can you use any api? There is no Database access, but can you get a JSON somehow? And can you use JavaScript? How ist the table structure (easy to read [copy])?

Answer (score -2):

Please try this code

```
    $.ajax({ 
        url:WEB_URL, 
        type:'GET', 
        success: function(data){
          $('#your_body').html($(data).find('#table_or_div').html());
        }
   });
```

Comment: He never said he wanted to use PHP.  You need to get more information from the user before answering.

Comment: Thanks this works, but it is not getting all the data I need. And I'd rather not be using PHP in this, JS is fine though,

Comment: Use $.ajax({
   url:WEB_URL,
   type:'GET',
   success: function(data){
       $('#your_body').html($(data).find('#table_or_div').html());
   }
});